# Change date format in Google Search

Tags: google-search

In Google, when you turn on web history, Google shows which links you have visited before and when. But the date format is in `MM/DD/YY` and I want to display it in the `DD/MM/YY` format:

[image: US-style dates]

Is there any way to show the date in my preferred format?

Comment: I’m not sure about this, so I won’t post it as an answer, but it might have something to do with the language/localization settings. Try changing these settings for your account/search.

Answer (score 1):

For me, yes, though it happens my default is what you would prefer. I can switch between the two however by using Google Search to search for `google` and at the bottom of the results page clicking on `Use Google.com`.

[image: WA50920 exmple]